# Iterate over an object's list data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to iterate over each number (and print it) that is associated with an object when it is initialized but only first element is returned and not the others. But this should work for normal for loop right?

```
   class Test():
        def __init__(self):
            self.data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
        def listelements(self):
            for i in self.data:
              return [i]


    a = Test()
    print(a.listelements())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `yield` instead of `return` as given below,

```
>>> class Test():
        def __init__(self):
            self.data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
        def listelements(self):
            for i in self.data:
              yield [i]


>>> a = Test()
>>> print(a.listelements()) # you can iterate through this generator
<generator object Test.listelements at 0x00000220E0D03E08>
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> for element in a.listelements():
        print(element)  
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
[6]
[7]
[8]
```

Answer (score 1):

No, `return` will break the for loop but `yield` won't. Please see the usage of python generator [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/7969188)

```py
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

    def listelements(self):
        for i in self.data:
            yield i


a = Test()
print(list(a.listelements())) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```